# Keep green giant arborvitae narrow

Tags: hedge, evergreens, cedar

I want a tall hedge but keep it up to 5ft wide (once grown).
I understand that for height I would need green giant arborvitae. However, they grow as wide as 15ft, whereas emerald green arborvitae would stay at 5ft wide.

Is there a way to keep the green giant 5ft wide or do I need to plant emerald green and give up the height?

Comment: What is the "tall height" you fail to mention?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I would like it more than 15ft tall if possible and up to 30ft.

Comment: Do you have, or will you get, equipment that lets you effectively shear a 30 foot tall hedge?  That's not a small job.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, I don't have the equipment but I am willing to buy it and learn or pay. If you could point me to learning material I will appreciate. If so, green giant is indeed a good option?

Comment: You should broaden your cultivar choice. For example, Taylor Junipers get at least 20 feet tall and only 3 feet wide. More details here, if you're interested: https://conifersociety.org/conifers/juniperus-virginiana-taylor/ This source shows a 25 ft height: https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/juniperus-virginiana-taylor/  And this source has 30 ft: https://www.monrovia.com/taylor-juniper.html. This tree would be perfect - yeah, you'd have to pay more (assuming it's available where you live), but you wouldn't have to spend the money to torture it into submission, either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other arborvitae cultivars than these two - one of which might be more suited, if you can answer the height question.

Prune / shear / "hedge trim" **compulsively.** That may require some serious equipment investment if you are aiming for a 50 foot tall hedge, and a 50 foot tall hedge will also fail on the next point at 5 feet wide.

And don't do it vertically. If you want the bottom to be heathy and full, the bottom is 5 feet wide and the top is significantly less, so the whole thing can get some sun.

A trapezoid with the narrower side on top, not a rectangle.

Comment: Thank you @Ecnerwal. 50 ft tall would be more than I need. I get the point of the shape narrowing towards the top. I opened these 2 species because I can get either of these at normal price for 20 plants + planting them...